# XEN Server 4.4.4 - Cannot create disk partition

Tags: linux, xen, parted

In an Oracle VM Server we created a 2nd partition on `/dev/sdb`, now we want to create the ext4 filesystem on it, but `mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb2` returns this:

`mke2fs 1.43-WIP (20-Jun-2013)
/dev/sdb2 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!`

Here's the result of `parted`:

```
[root@OVSGRIENSU ~]# parted /dev/sdb
GNU Parted 2.1
Using /dev/sdb
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Model: IBM ServeRAID M5210e (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 999GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name    Flags
 1      1049kB  53.7GB  53.7GB  ext4
 2      53.7GB  999GB   945GB                datos1
```

As you can see, this disk is handled by the RAID controller IBM ServerRAID M5210e. This is a one disk array, the only way to let the O.S. see each disk was this.

How can we create a filesystem for /dev/sdb2?.

*Edit:* Requested data by @anx:

```
mount

/dev/sdb1 on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
/dev/sda2 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,umask=0077,shortname=winnt)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
xenfs on /proc/xen type xenfs (rw)
none on /var/lib/xenstored type tmpfs (rw)
/dev/sda4 on /mnt/datos1 type ext4 (rw)
```

dmraid -r

```
no raid disks
```

cat /proc/mdstat

```
Personalities : 
unused devices: <none>
```